# Inconsistent accessibility: return type

Tags: c#, .net

I have an public interface:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    Task<List<Data>> GetAll(string type);
}
```

And a DataService class that implements it:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public async Task<List<Data>> GetAll(string type)
    {
        
    }

}
```

Now I get the error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Task<List<Data>>' is less accessible than method 'DataService.GetAll(string)'
```

What is wrong with this implementation? Everything is public imho.

Comment: Is `Data` public?

Comment: Are you _sure_ `Data` is public. Perhaps its public nested within a private class, or private nested within a public class (note the default is private if omitted)

Comment: Just make the Data type public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data` class needs to be public. You cannot use less visibility level since the return type of the public method is needed to be public.

Comment: It was so simple... thanks!